# make file not working for s3fs

Tags: macos, makefile, s3fs

Hi i am trying to install s3fs but i am getting the following error.

```
*** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

any ideas i am following the installation tutorial
http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/InstallationNotes

heres my terminal code i am using mac os x lion.

```
stealth:cd ~/Desktop
stealth:Desktop sam$cd s3fs-1.61
stealth:s3fs-1.61 sam$ ./configure --prefix=/sam
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for DEPS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (fuse >= 2.8.4 libcurl >= 7.0 libxml-2.0 >= 2.6 libcrypto >= 0.9) were not met:

No package 'fuse' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DEPS_CFLAGS
and DEPS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
stealth:s3fs-1.61 sam$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

any help please???

Answer (score 0):

The script output tells you what to do,

install fuse, libcurl, libxml and libcrypto

Instead of doing this manual i would do this with a package management framework like e.g. MacPorts

Answer (score 0):

I've jsut faced with such issue (RHEL 6.4, x86_64). The main reason was:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (fuse >= 2.8.4 libcurl >= 7.0 libxml-2.0 >= 2.6 libcrypto >= 0.9) were not met:
No package 'fuse' found
```

my solutions is the folowing:

```
cd /usr/src/
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/fuse/fuse-2.X/2.9.3/fuse-2.9.3.tar.gz
tar -xzf ./fuse-2.9.3.tar.gz
cd ./fuse-2.9.3
./configure
make && make install
cd /usr/src/
wget http://s3fs.googlecode.com/files/s3fs-1.71.tar.gz
tar -xzf ./s3fs-1.71.tar.gz
cd ./s3fs-1.71
```

then we are trying to configure it:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

but if fails :) So, we need to add fuse in pkgconfig and export pfgconfig:

```
cp /usr/src/fuse-2.9.3/fuse.pc /usr/lib64/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
```

trying confugure it again with success and do make && make install:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make && make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem installing **s3fs** on OS X earlier today. The **make** configuration isn't working because the `fuse` binary isn't available in path. To fix the issue [install fuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/) then re-run `./configure`. Once complete you'll be able to run `make` to compile the source code.